# Commutation relation between function and operator

Tags: functions, commutative-algebra

Show that $[p, V(x)] = V'(x)[p, x]$ , where $p$ is an operator, and $V(x)$ is an analytic function. I don't quite understand what the brackets [] do to an operator, but for matrices we use them to mean [A,B] = AB - BA.

The actual question I'm trying to answer is 'show that $[p, V(x)] = i\hbar V'(x)T$ ', which is satisfied if this: $[p, V(x)] = V'(x)[p, x]$ is true, because I'm also given that $[p, x] = i \hbar T$ and $[S,T]=0$. There's probably an alternative way of proving this relation, but I unfortunately haven't manage to prove either. Thanks for any help or hints!

Attempt to answer the actual question I've been asked:
$$[p_x, V(a)] \psi = (p_xV(a) - V(a)p_x)\psi$$
$$=-i\hbar \frac{\partial({V(a) \psi})}{\partial{x}}+i\hbar V(a) \frac{\partial{\psi}}{\partial{x}}$$
$$= -i\hbar \frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{x}}$$
Not 100% sure what to do from there. Very close, but I have to get T from somewhere.

Comment: Are we supposed to guess what all of these objects are?

Comment: Ah sorry, I'll add what I know!

Comment: An operator on what? An analytical function from where to where? Are these Lie brackets?

Comment: I don't know what the operator operates on, and it's analytical in the sense that the Taylor expansion exists and converges I think, although that also isn't specified. The brackets are commutators but I only know how they apply to matrices, so [A,B] = AB - BA.

Comment: Think of $V(x)$ not as of a function but rather as of an operator of multiplication by $V(x)$, i.e. $V(x)[f(x)] \equiv V(x) \cdot f(x)$.

Comment: @mavzolej I can expand and apply to some test function $f(x)$ to get $pVf(x) - Vpf(x)$ and I think that's treating it like an operator of multiplication, but where does differentiation come into it? I can't get any further.

Comment: Since your potential is a function of $x$, you are using the usual representation of the position and momentum operators, in which $\hat{x}$ is just the multiplication by $x$, while the momentum is $\hat{p} =\dfrac{\hbar}{i} \dfrac{\partial} {\partial x}$.

Comment: @mavzolej I have actually tried substituting in the momentum operator. I get a missing $T$ if I follow it through. Shall I add my working to the original post?

Comment: Missing $T$ if I apply my result to the actual question I'm trying to answer, I mean.

Comment: @mavzolej Added some workings. Treating V like an operator of multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{gather}
[\hat{p},\hat{x}^k]
= [\hat{p},\hat{x}^{k-1}\cdot \hat{x}]
= [\hat{p},\hat{x}^{k-1}] \hat{x} +  \hat{x}^{k-1}[\hat{p}, \hat{x}] \\
= [\hat{p},\hat{x}^{k-2}\cdot\hat{x}] \hat{x} +  \hat{x}^{k-1} (i \hbar \hat{T})
= \ldots = k \hat{x}^{k-1} (i \hbar \hat{T}) \quad;
\end{gather}
\begin{gather}
[\hat{p},V(\hat{x})]
=[\hat{p},\sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k!} V^{(k)}(0)\hat{x}^k]
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k!} V^{(k)}(0)[\hat{p},\hat{x}^k]\\
= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k!} V^{(k)}(0)k \hat{x}^{k-1} (i \hbar \hat{T})
= V'(\hat{x}) (i \hbar \hat{T}) \quad.
\end{gather}

Now, there's something that bothers me in this solution. Namely, if I do
\begin{gather}
[\hat{p},\hat{x}^k]
= [\hat{p},\hat{x} \cdot \hat{x}^{k-1}]
= [\hat{p},\hat{x}] \hat{x}^{k-1} +  \hat{x}[\hat{p}, \hat{x}^{k-1}]
= \ldots = k \hat{x}^{k-1} (i \hbar \hat{T}) \quad,
\end{gather}
it leads to the wrong result, $(i \hbar \hat{T}) V'(\hat{x})$.

Anyways, the truth is out there.

Comment: No that's brilliant! T isn't an operator it's a constant, it can go wherever! Amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: For the constant - true. But still, I'm a little puzzled about the general case.

Comment: Actually my mistake, it isn't a constant. However x and T commute so the result holds, although presumably only for the case when xT-Tx = 0.